# selenium ide verify a = b when a =1234 and b =1,234 using replace function

Tags: selenium, replace, ide

I have value 1234 stored in variable abc and value 1,234 stored in variable def. I want to use replace function to prove that a = b

```
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>//div[@id='messages-div']/span[22]</td>
<td>abc</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>storeText</td>
<td>//table[@id='keys']/tbody/tr[22]</td>
<td>def</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 assert(abc.replaceAll(",","").equals(def.replaceAll(",","")));
```